# Open Source XPath Filter 2.0 implementation

Tags: java, xml, xpath, open-source, xml-signature

Does anyone know of an open source implementation for [XPath Filter 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-filter2/), preferrably in Java? But any other language would also be fine. The standard is not that new, so something should exist, but I can't find anything...

If there really is nothing adequate, has anyone ever implemented it and could tell me how difficult it is getting there with standard means (DOM model plus XPath)? Just a rough estimate, would it be a matter of days or rather of weeks for 2 people working full time on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a look at the **[Apache Santuario](http://santuario.apache.org/index.html)** library?

It comes with a class that implements *XML Signature XPath Filter v2.0*:

[`TransformXPath2Filter`](http://santuario.apache.org/Java/api/org/apache/xml/security/transforms/implementations/TransformXPath2Filter.html)

Further implementations are listed here (though I haven't checked any of these):

> [**XML Signature XPath Filter2 Interop Report**](http://www.w3.org/Signature/2002/05/xmldsig-filter2-interop.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link! I added an answer with what we found out for completion.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to 0xA3. The interoperability report lists the following two open source libraries that support XPath Filter 2:

- [Apache Santuario](http://santuario.apache.org/index.html)
- [xmlsec (C)](http://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/)

In our own analysis, we found out that the [JDK-internal implementation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/crypto/dsig/Transform.html#XPATH2) of XML Digital Signatures also supports the feature, although in an implicit way, the implementation is not public API and hidden from the user. As the entire XML-DSIG implementation in the Sun/Oracle JDK, it uses a version of the Apache Santuario implementation internally.

We finally settled for [Jaxen](http://jaxen.codehaus.org/releases.html) because it was easier to integrate than Santuario.